# Conditional distribution of random sample from Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

I'm dealing with this problem for a while, and although I have some intuition, I think I'm missing something, please take a look:

We are given a random sample $X_1, X_2,...,X_n$ from Poisson$(\theta)$ distribution. I'm asked to prove that the conditional distribution of: $X_1, X_2,...,X_{n-1}$  given $Y=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is multinomial.

What I have tried so far:

$P(X_1, X_2,...,X_{n-1} \mid Y = y) = \frac{P(X_1, X_2,...,X_{n-1},Y = y)}{P(Y=y)}$

Then, although I know the $n-1$ samples of $X_i$ are independent among each other, and that I could get their joint pdf easily, the problem comes up when I need to related such joint pdf to the pdf of $Y$. Since, I'm not sure whether they are independent, otherwise, the product of the pdfs would suffice.

I know that $Y \sim \text{Poisson}(n\theta)$.

Any clue?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

We have $$ P(X_1=x_1,\ldots, X_{n-1}=x_{n-1}, Y=y) = P(X_1=x_1,\ldots, X_{n-1}=x_{n-1}, X_n=y-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_i) \\=f(x_1)f(x_2)\ldots f(x_{n-1}) f\left(y-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_i \right)$$ where $$f(x) = \frac{\theta^xe^{-\theta}}{x!}$$

Comment: Oh.. I see, Good hint. I'm gonna work on it.. and come back. Hopefully would be able to get some help from you. Thanks!

Comment: OK. I worked out the conditional distribution:
$ \frac{P(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2,...,X_{n-1}=x_{n-1},X_n = y - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i)}{P(Y=y)}$

And obtained:

$\frac{y!}{\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i!} \cdot \frac{1}{n^y (y- \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i) !}$

Do you guys recognize the multinomial distribution somehow?

Comment: @htennek2k That doesn't look wrong math-wise, but can't say I do. Are you sure you aren't actually supposed to compute $$ P(X_1=x_1,\ldots, X_n=x_n\mid Y=y)$$ where $Y=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$?

Comment: Well, literally, the problem says:
Show that the conditional pdf of $X_1,X_2,...,X_{n-1}$, given $Y=y$, is multinomial.

This is from Introduction to Mathematical Statistics of Hogg, Problem 7.6.6.

Comment: Thanks for your reply though. What I got seems similar to the multinomial distribution, but cannot see the relation with those odd factors I get in the denominator.

Comment: @htennek2k Well, is $Y = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} X_i$ then? I have the seventh edition of that book and the problem is not the same. See my edit... the alternative I suggest results in a multinomial, and the problem as stated does not. I suspect it may just be a typo on the book's part.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using the 7th edition too. I'm trying to prove what is asked in the Hint of part (a).

Comment: @htennek2k ahh I see it now. And looking at the treatment of the multinomial in the book, I see the reason for the discrepancy: since one of the degrees of freedom of the multinomial distribution (as it is on the wikipedia sidebar) is redundant they treat the last degree of freedom in the multinomial distribution as an abbreviation for $y-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i$ and think of it as a distribution for $(x_1,\ldots x_{n-1})$ rather than for $(x_1,\ldots, x_n).$ If you write the multinomial with the abbreviation substituted for and with $p_i = 1/n$, you will see it matches what you have above

Comment: Ok, then it seem that my result might be correct, and by rearranging the factors we get:

$\frac{y!}{\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i!  (y - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i)! } \frac{1}{n^y} $. 

So, the $(y - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i)!$ factor, will be like the last $x_k$ in wikipedia right? then, my final guess is that the $1/n^y$ must relate to the product of those $p_k$'s in the wikipedia expression?

Comment: @htennek2k Yep, that's right. Unfortunately, we have a terminology clash with $n$ in this problem being like $k$ in the multinomial parametrization and $y$ in this problem corresponding to the $n$ parameter. Sticking with the problem's notation, we get $$ p_1^{x_1}\ldots p_{n-1}^{x_{n-1}}p_n^{x_n} = p_1^{x_1}\ldots p_{n-1}^{x_{n-1}} p_n^{y-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i} $$ when we substitute in for the abbreviation. Then, letting all $p_i=1/n,$ reduces this to $1/n^y$

Comment: Oh.. that's awesome. Yeah. I figured out that our $y$ corresponds to $n$ in the wikipedia article.  Great, thanks for your help. Everyday I learn something thanks to people like you.